# How to calculate end IP in the range, based on start IP and network mask length in JAVA

Tags: java, postgresql, maxmind

I'm experimenting with the MaxMind GeoIP (Geo lite 2) DB.

In source file GeoLite2-Country-Blocks.csv from (GeoLite2-Country-CSV.zip) from MaxMind site, I have this line:

::ffff:87.197.0.0,112,3057568,3057568,,,,,0,0

I have a starting IPv4 IP address ::ffff:87.197.0.0 and I have the IPv6 network mask length 112, how can I calculate the last IP in the range in JAVA ?

The reason is I'm importing the MaxMind Geo lite 2 database in CSV format into a PostgreSQL database, so I need import start IP address into one DB column and last IP address into another DB column.

thanks.

Ivan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Postgres, you should use the [cidr or inet type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-net-types.html). With those types, you can insert the data in the form `::ffff:87.197.0.0/112` (or `87.197.0.0/16` for the non-IPv6 mapped address). Using the network types, you can take advantage of Pg's [network functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-net.html) when doing queries.

Comment: thanks for you answer, i used cidr type in my table. In postgreSQL DB, in "blocks" table (import data from GeoLite2-City-Blocks.csv) I have columns: "network_start_ip" cidr NOT NULL, "network_mask_length" integer NOT NULL. please, can You tell me, SQL select statement, how can I check my IP address, for example: 87.197.148.121 ?

Comment: You should have just one column, not two. The data should be inserted in the form `{network_start_ip}/{network_mask_length}`, which represents a particular subnet. Once you do that, you can use the network operators that I linked to above.